# Trying to understand NVDIMMs vs. Intel's and Micron's 3D XPoint Technology

Tags: memory, ssd

As far as I understand, an NVDIMM (non-volatile dual in-line memory module) is hybrid computer memory that retains data during a service outage. NVDIMMs integrate non-volatile NAND flash memory with dynamic random access memory (DRAM) and dedicated backup power on a single memory subsystem.
I also know there are several standards (NVDIMM-F, NVDIMM-N, NVDIMM-P).

As I read in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVDIMM#Types), emerging memory technologies aim to achieve NVDIMM without a cache or two separate memories. Intel and Micron have announced use of the 3D XPoint PCM technology in NVDIMM-F.

What I cannot understand is the connection beween the 3D XPoint PCM (and other technologies that try to overcome the need of two separate memories) and the NVDIMMs. They seem opposite to me.

Can you please explain the sentence "Intel and Micron have announced use of the 3D XPoint PCM technology in NVDIMM-F"?

Comment: I left some useful(?) comments before this got migrated, but they seem to have gotten lost!  :(  The summary was that 3DXPoint is one way of implementing an NV-DIMM, Flash + battery-backed RAM is another.  I think 3DXPoint has better read and write performance than Flash, and much better write endurance.

Comment: Ah, it's still there if you look at [the noredirect=1 version on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097713/trying-to-understand-nvdimms-vs-intels-and-microns-3d-xpoint-technology?noredirect=1)